# TScrollbox scrolling using mouse wheel in c++ builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have added a scroll box inside a tabsheet in my form. I am able to scroll the contents when i clicked scroll up and down button in scroll box. But i want to scroll the contents using mouse wheel up and down. I have tried the below code.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ScrollBox1MouseWheelUp(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift,
      TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
{
    Form1->ScrollBox1->VertScrollBar->Position -= 3;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::ScrollBox1MouseWheelDown(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift,
      TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
{
    Form1->ScrollBox1->VertScrollBar->Position += 3;
}
```

But the scrolling is not happening and control does not come over here when i tried to debug it. How to do scrolling using mouse wheel in scroll box?

Comment: You need to treat message WM_MOUSEWHEEL, check whether target window is Scrollbox1 and execute scroll for it

Answer (score 3):

You could  implement the `MouseWheel` event on the owner form, and then test for Control under mouse is a TScrollBox:

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  i: Integer;
  TheScrollBox: TScrollBox;
  Control: TWinControl;
begin
  Control := FindVCLWindow(Mouse.CursorPos);
  Handled := Control is TScrollBox;

  if not Handled then
    exit;

  TheScrollBox := Control as TScrollBox;

  for i := 1 to Mouse.WheelScrollLines do
    try
      if WheelDelta > 0 then
        TheScrollBox.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0)
      else
        TheScrollBox.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
    finally
      TheScrollBox.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_ENDSCROLL, 0);
    end;
end;
```

Another and more generic approach would be to implement Application.OnMessage :

Add a `TApplicationEvents` component to you mainform and the implement a OnMessageEvent :

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  i, Count: Integer;
  Control: TWinControl;
begin
  if Msg.message <> WM_MOUSEWHEEL then
    exit;

  Control := FindVCLWindow(Mouse.CursorPos);
  Handled := Control <> nil;

  if not Handled then
    exit;

  Count := 1;
  if Smallint(loWord(Msg.wParam)) = MK_CONTROL then
    Count := 5;

  try
    for i := 1 to Count do
      if Smallint(HiWord(Msg.wParam)) > 0 then
        Control.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0)
      else
        Control.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
  finally
    Control.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_ENDSCROLL, 0);
  end;
end;
```

PS: WPARAM and LPARAM is documented in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645614(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I used TStringGrid component inside the scroll box and the focus is on the string grind only when i moved to that tabsheet. Thats why mouse wheel event of scroll box was not working i think. I am not sure. Then I used main form mouse wheel up and down event and checked whether the active tab sheet is the sheet contains the scroll box and performed scrolling. It is working fine now.

Comment: I just placed some buttons on a scrollbox when I was testing

Comment: I Changed the focus from string grid to scroll box by setting the focus to the scroll box on clicking it and i tried with Scroll box mouse wheel up and down. It is also working fine now.